# Sequelizejs-- how to write datetime to MSSQL

Tags: javascript, sql-server, sqlite

I am using sequelizejs. My DB is Mssql. I have problem when writing data to a table. This is the erorr I get:

> Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

My table is simple only two fields, plus two datetime that are generated by Sequalize, createdAt and updatedAt. I believe Sequalize is sending wrong datetime to SQL server for those two fields.

The same code write without problems to Sqlite table, same structure

Comment: Thing is that Sequalize is doing it behind the scenes. I would not want to change the library, unless I absolutely must.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. In SQL server I manually changed datetime to datetime2 and it worked without problems.